# How to extract a value of a JSON object using Regular expression

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a JSON string. I want to extract the matched value of my regular expression.

```
{
    "EX1": {
        "Test1": {
            "Fruit": "Apple"
        },
        "Test2": {
            "vegetable": "Tomato"
        },
        "Test3": {
            "SoftDrink": "Pepsi"
        }
    },
    "EX2": {
        "Test1": {
            "Fruit": "Apple"
        },
        "Test2": {
            "vegetable": "Tomato"
        },
        "Test3": {
            "SoftDrink": "Pepsi"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to pass a regular expression like "*.Test3.SoftDrink", it has to search both JSON objects and has to return a value Pepsi form EX1 and EX2.

## Expected output:

Pepsi
Pepsi

Comment: Why do you need a regular expression for this? You can just deserialize the JSON string, then access the members directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using regular expressions, you could deserialize the JSON into a `dict` with [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads), then access the members directly:

```
from json import loads

json = """{
    "EX1": {
        "Test1": {
            "Fruit": "Apple"
        },
        "Test2": {
            "vegetable": "Tomato"
        },
        "Test3": {
            "SoftDrink": "Pepsi"
        }
    },
    "EX2": {
        "Test1": {
            "Fruit": "Apple"
        },
        "Test2": {
            "vegetable": "Tomato"
        },
        "Test3": {
            "SoftDrink": "Pepsi"
        }
    }
}"""

d = loads(json)

for key in d:
    print(d[key]['Test3']['SoftDrink'])
```

**Output:**

```
Pepsi
Pepsi
```

You could also print them directly without a loop:

```
print(d['EX1']['Test3']['SoftDrink'])
# Pepsi

print(d['EX2']['Test3']['SoftDrink'])
# Pepsi
```